# Import trace for requested module / next js 13 / app directory / mongoose mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npm, mongoose, next.js

There are a lot of errors in my application console.
How to fix it?

Next js 13.2 / app directory

```
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-user-agent-node/dist-cjs/is-crt-available.js
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/util-user-agent-node/dist-cjs/index.js
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity/dist-cjs/runtimeConfig.js
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity/dist-cjs/CognitoIdentityClient.js
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity/dist-cjs/index.js
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-providers/dist-cjs/fromCognitoIdentity.js
./node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-providers/dist-cjs/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./Total/db/connect.js
./Part/ssr/Ssr.js
./app/(pages)/profile/page.js

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bson.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'bson-ext' in 'C:\Users\79833\WebstormProjects\partApp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bson.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./Total/db/connect.js
./Part/ssr/Ssr.js
./app/(pages)/profile/page.js

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'kerberos' in 'C:\Users\79833\WebstormProjects\partApp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./Total/db/connect.js
./Part/ssr/Ssr.js
./app/(pages)/profile/page.js

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd' in 'C:\Users\79833\WebstormProjects\partApp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./Total/db/connect.js
./Part/ssr/Ssr.js
./app/(pages)/profile/page.js
```

I have tried updating and reinstalling packages. The error does not go away.

These are not all errors. There are many others. They also look

Answer (score 3):

These are the things i've learned by spending time using mongoose 7 with latest nextjs version:

Make sure that mongoose is not imported inside client components ! (Which were creating Can't resolve errors that you are facing)

And if you are using mongoose 7, I have to put serverComponentsExternalPackages option in next.config.js (even with the fix given here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42277)

```js
/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
    experimental: { appDir: true, serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"] },
    webpack(config) {
        config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
        return config;
    }
};
```

I would also change your export by

```js
const Product = mongoose.models && "Product" in mongoose.models ? mongoose.models. Product : mongoose.model("Product", PostSchema);
export default Product;
```

my project https://github.com/mathieuguyot/adventures have mongoose 7 integrated with next 13.2.4, maybe it can help you in any way :)

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs you have to export the schema like this this will fix your issue

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    image:{type:String, required:true},
},{timestamps : true})


export default mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema); //like this try to export every model in you app like this and it should work
```

Answer (score 0):

### You have 2 solutions to resolve this.

**Install encoding**
As suggested in other issues, you can install encoding on our own locally.

`npm i -D encoding`

**Ignore warning in next.config.js**
If you prefer to avoid installing another (unused) lib, you can simply ignore the warning through webpack config inside `next.config.js`

```
webpack: config => {
  /* On `node-fetch` v2, that `supabase-js` uses,
  `encoding` package was optionally required for `.textConverted`
  which means it wasn't in `node-fetch` deps.
  See: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/412.
  Since `encoding` is not part of the deps by default, when using with webpack,
  it will raise a warning message.
  This can be ignored as it doesn't prevent anything to work well. */
  config.ignoreWarnings = [
    { module: /node_modules\/node-fetch\/lib\/index\.js/ },
    { file: /node_modules\/node-fetch\/lib\/index\.js/ },
  ];

  return config;
}
```

Ref: [NextJS Discussion Board](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49432#discussioncomment-5884572)

Answer (score 0):

To my best understanding i feel the "Import trace for requested module" message itself is not an error but rather a helpful tool/message for understanding the import chain in your Netjs project

Answer (score -1):

It seems that some users are experiencing issues with a bug, and I have found a solution that may help:

1. Firstly, check your current version of node js, and update it to the latest version (node 16).
2. Once updated, reinstall your nodemodules.
3. Make a build.

This should resolve the issue. It is important to ensure that the instructions are followed carefully in order to avoid any further issues.